# C# Printing Reports with dot matrix printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing, dllimport

I have dot matrix printer, but when I print it some of the characters doesn't accept, like degrees(°), diameter(Ø), number with power of two(2²) and etc. Take a look at the photos.

[EXAMPLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvVLU.jpg)

When printing it shows a black SQUARE.

**This is the line code.**

MyPrinter.Print((char)15 + " itemname.Text " + "\r\n");

**This is the Class code**

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    /*=================================================*/

    private IntPtr HandlePrinter;
    public PrinterSettings ps;

    public LPrinter()
    {
        HandlePrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        ps = new PrinterSettings();
    }
   public PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    public string PrinterName
    {
        get
        {
            return ps.PrinterName;
        }
        set
        {
            ps.PrinterName = value;
        }
    }



    public bool Open(string DocName)
    {
        // see if printer is already open
        if (HandlePrinter != IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        // opens the printer
        bool risp = OpenPrinter(ps.PrinterName, out HandlePrinter, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (risp == false) return false;

        // starts a print job
        DOCINFOA MyDocInfo = new DOCINFOA();
        MyDocInfo.pDocName = DocName;
        MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = null;
        MyDocInfo.pDataType = "RAW";

        if (StartDocPrinter(HandlePrinter, 1, MyDocInfo))
        {
            StartPagePrinter(HandlePrinter); //starts a page       
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public bool Close()
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
        if (!EndPagePrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        if (!EndDocPrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        if (!ClosePrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        HandlePrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Print(string outputstring)
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(outputstring);

        Int32 done = 0;
        bool ok = WritePrinter(HandlePrinter, buf, outputstring.Length, out done);

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf);

        if (!ok) return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

Hope someone can help me to fix this.

Comment: Do you work in a museum o_O ? I'd be very surprised if anyone is up-to-date on current dot matrix technology... I think most people who would know about this have long since retired?! I've been an engineer for 20 years and I haven't seen one of these since I was in high school

Comment: FYI A dot-matrix and a dot matrix printer are totally different things

Comment: @Liam Yes, eventually my company is very old, and they want to keep it cheap as it can be, when printing in dot matrix it's cheaper than buying bond paper. Our dot matrix is only used for a whole year reports.

Comment: @Liam i have an Epson LX310 printer. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @Liam I just upgraded their system, can you imagine it's 2022 and they still using FoxPro. and now I'm struggling with this because I can't fix the problem above.

Comment: do you have a windows10 driver for the printer, the printer is pre-unicode, so you have to encode the page in a different encoding that the printer understands, it has USB port so it is not that old

Comment: @rioV8 I think the driver is not the problem. It has to do with the converting string to unicode or Ansi. and that's the cuase it doesn't accept some special characters. like degrees or diameter, etc.